# How to fetch data from database individually in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a ecommerce site. Trying to create a `product-details` page where when clicking on a button it give me details of just that item. Database already created and connected but keep getting all items when clicking on one item instead of just the one I clicked on. Can I do it by `id`?

Here is my **details.php** code

```
  <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'Test');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured=1";
    $featured = $con->query($sql); ?>
   
    <div class="col">   <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="row">
         <h2 class="text-center">Product Details</h2>
         <?php 
         
           while($product =mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)):
   
         
         ?>
         <div class="col-md-5">
           <h4> <?= $product['title'];?></h4>
           <img src="<?= $product['images'];?>" height="200px" width="300px" alt="<?= 
           $product['title']; ?>" />
           <p class="price">Price: <?= $product['price'];?></p>
           <p class="desc">Description: <?= $product['description'];?></p>
           <p class="bname">Brandname: <?= $product['brandname'];?></p>
           
           
         </div>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
       </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: If you just want to get one record, you do not need the while loop, just retrieve the one with id=? and then display that record

Comment: Can you show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: while clicking the button you need to get the productId and pass it into select so you can get the output....using Jquery

Comment: OK, please see my suggested answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the while block (you only need to retrieve one record)
2. change the query to something like `select * from [table] where id=?`
3. bind the id parameter and execute the prepared statement

Hence, Please change your code to :

```
 <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'Test');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured=1 and id=?";
   
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i',$_GET["id"]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $featured = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
?>
   
    <div class="col">   <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="row">
         <h2 class="text-center">Product Details</h2>
      <?php 
      $product =mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured);     
      // while($product =mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)):      
      ?>
         <div class="col-md-5">
           <h4> <?= $product['title'];?></h4>
           <img src="<?= $product['images'];?>" height="200px" width="300px" alt="<?= 
           $product['title']; ?>" />
           <p class="price">Price: <?= $product['price'];?></p>
           <p class="desc">Description: <?= $product['description'];?></p>
           <p class="bname">Brandname: <?= $product['brandname'];?></p>
           
           
         </div>
         <?php 
          //endwhile; 
         ?>

       </div> 
    </div>
```

Now just call the PHP (say thru a hyperlink) by details.php?id=xxxx

For example , if you want to retrieve the record of id=10, then visit **details.php?id=10**